# Can I access a QPROPERTY declared as MEMBER in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qproperty

I have a `QQuickItem` class with some members used in QML, so they are declared like this :

```
Q_PROPERTY (bool myBool MEMBER _myBool NOTIFY myBoolChanged)
```

If I want to access to this member in C++ code (from another class), do I have a *free* get-accessor ? What is its syntax ?

The doc is unclear to me :

> A MEMBER variable association is required if no READ accessor function
>   is specified. This makes the given member variable readable and
>   writable without the need of creating READ and WRITE accessor
>   functions.

Does this make the member *readable* and *writable* only in QML or also in C++ ?

Comment: did you read the docs? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html

Comment: I did yes, and it did not answer this specific question from what I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt doesn't generate any C++ API getter for you, but the property value can be [read](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaproperty.html#read) via the meta-object system if you want to go that way:

```
QMetaProperty prop = obj->metaObject()->property(...);
bool value = prop.read(obj).toBool();
```

Unless you're working on something generic based on the meta-object system, you might want to define a normal getter for use in C++. The MEMBER keyword for Q_PROPERTY is not a shortcut around standard programming practices.

Answer (score 4):

Qt **does not** create a "C++" getter or setter. 
With MEMBER the Qt MetaSystem gets only access directly to the member variable.

With the MEMBER keyword something like that will be created in the moc file:

```
Q_PROPERTY(int prop MEMBER m_prop NOTIFY propChanged) 
....
else if (_c == QMetaObject::ReadProperty) { 
void *_v = _a[0]; 
switch (_id) { 
case 0: *reinterpret_cast< int*>(_v) = m_prop; break; 
....
```

And with the READ keyword something like that will be created in the moc file:

```
Q_PROPERTY(int prop READ getProp NOTIFY propChanged) 
...
else if (_c == QMetaObject::ReadProperty) { 
void *_v = _a[0]; 
switch (_id) { 
case 0: *reinterpret_cast< int*>(_v) = getProp(); break; 
...
```